# Footnotes are not correctly linked

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, incompatibility, hyperlink

I'm writing my thesis and using a lot of packages. When I create a `\footnote`, the number appears with a link, but when I click the document goes to the first page. I read about some packages that should be in an specific order, like `setspace`, `hyperref` and `cleveref`. I put this packages in the correct order but the problem was not resolved. Any help?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[%
    inline,     
    shortlabels 
]{enumitem}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[%
    font=footnotesize,      
    justification=centering,
    figurewithin=section,
    tablewithin=section
]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{secdot}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[%
noabbrev,
nameinlink
]{cleveref} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents            
\newpage                
\section{Section}
This is some text\footnote{This is a footnote.}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe start with a document with no package and then add package after package until the problem arises. This is my typical approach to narrow it down before posting a question.

Comment: Load bookmark after hyperref.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It didn't work

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I follow your recomendation, and only when I don't use the `setspace` package it works

Comment: @DanielValenciaC. Load `setspace` before `footnotebackref`?

Comment: (I am traveling and can't help more directly). Then now reduce the example code to the minimum (but still showing the error). Delete all packages that are not necessary in order to reproduce the problem. This is called a MWE (google it).

Comment: Do you need setspace.  I seem to recall that it does nothing useful with lots of bad side effects.